# Why would I use HNM (high noise margin) gate drive over a TTL gate drive for DC motor driving application?

Tags: analog, noise, logic-gates, ttl, gate-driving

I am making a very simple half bridge DC motor drive using the [MAX1760](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX17600-MAX17605.pdf) gate driver. Looking through the datasheet I saw that it offers two types of logic level technologies (if that's the right word?); TTL and HNM. This may be a simple question, but why would someone want to use HNM over TTL? What trade offs do we make if we select HNM? Although I framed the question for DC motor application, I am interested in applications in broader sense too.